# First Letter not working in Firefox

Tags: html, css

I have checked the other questions posted here but nothing seems to work for me. My :first-letter css works in everything but Firefox. Can anyone see what is wrong in my code that is causing this?

Live page is here: http://inventivewebdesign.com/uctest/

CSS

```
quote-box {
    background-color: #EDEDED;
    border: 2px solid #EDEDED;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin: 20px auto 20px;
    min-width: 400px;
    padding: 40px 50px 30px 50px;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    width: 80%;
    z-index: 10;
    font-style: italic;
}   

.quote-box:before{
    content:""; 
    display:block; 
    position:absolute; 
    z-index:-1; 
    top:10px; 
    left:10px; 
    right:10px; 
    bottom:10px; 
    border:2px solid #fff;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px
    }
.quote-box .leftquote {
    background: url("imgs/quote-l.png") top left no-repeat;
    height: 60px;
    width: 50px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 20px; 
    top: 15px;
    z-index:-1;
}
.quote-box .rightquote {
    background: url("imgs/quote-r.png") no-repeat scroll right bottom rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    height: 60px;
    width: 50px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 20px;
    bottom: 15px;
    z-index:-1;
}

.quote-box:first-letter {font-size:250%; }
.quote-box:first-line { line-height: 100%; }
```

HTML

```
<div class="quote-box">
     <span class="leftquote">&nbsp;</span>
         We are united. United with customers by collaborating every step...
     <span class="rightquote">&nbsp;</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Working fine for me in Firefox, *edit* nevermind, I just realized you put a class of first-let on the live example.

Comment: Sorry, Thought I had taken that out before I posted. Not there now.

Comment: I would try wrapping the text in a `p` tag and then applying the pseudo selector to the paragraph.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think @theMarceloR was on the right track. It looks like Firefox is trying to apply the pseudo class to the non-breaking space instead of the text. I wrapped the text in a p tag and changed the pseudo selector to target the paragraph and it seems to be working now.

```
<div class="quote-box">
 <span class="leftquote">&nbsp;</span>
 <p>We are united. United with customers by collaborating every step...</p>
 <span class="rightquote">&nbsp;</span>
</div>

.quote-box p:first-letter {font-size:250%; }
.quote-box p:first-line { line-height: 100%; }
```

## [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/X8y2r/2/)

Comment: This would be awesome, if I wasn't using wordpress. Wordpress takes out any <p> tags automatically. Also, why wouldn't it work if I just remove the &nbsp; and the span?

Comment: You guys are definately on the right track. If I wrap it in another div with another class it works. I was hoping for a better solution since this could get deleted by the client when making changes in the future.

Comment: You can disable the Wordpress paragraph filter by placing the following code directly beneath your `the_content()` tag:

`<?php remove_filter ('the_content', 'wpautop'); ?>`

I'm not sure why removing the nbsp is not working.

Comment: So I removed the non-breaking space and reconfigured the css to still add the left quote without it. Now it is just <div class="quote-box">We are united. United with customers by collaborating every step...<span class="rightquote">&nbsp;</span></div> and it still doesn't work. See here: http://inventivewebdesign.com/uctest/?page_id=22

Comment: I would say the best option would be to use the P tag route and then apply the filter removal above to prevent Wordpress from stripping out the P tags.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that you have a special character right at the beginning of your .quote-box div should be messing up your style. Have you tried without this line?

```
<span class="leftquote">&nbsp;</span>
```

Comment: I removed it now but still no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Firefox will see the `&nbsp;` as a character where Opera will ignore this and move to a "real" first character. So put your `&nbsp;` inside another `<p></p>` tag and it will work.

Example:

```html
<p>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</p><p>Hello world!</p>
```

instead of:

```html
<p>&nbsp;&nbsp; Hello world!</p>
```

Comment: My examples don´t show, the `<p></p>` tags are eaten by stackoverflow. I´ll try again here.
´<p>&nbsp;</p><p>Hello world!</p>` instead of `<p>&nbsp; Hello world!</p>`

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. Instead of this...

```
<div class="quote-box">
 <div><!-- floated div --></div>
 We are united.
</div>
```

Move the first word. If the div is floated, it renders the same and the :first-letter works again.

```
<div class="quote-box">
 We <div><!-- floated div --></div>
 are united.
</div>
```

That said, this seems like a bug in Firefox.